# How to do 'minimum Quantity' validation in opencart product page

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I am looking for minimum Quantity validation in opencart product page, but what happens is if any user changes the minimum Quantity to '0' or any alphabet it say successfully added instead of error

you can see in this eg. 
http://demo.opencart.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=43

I am adding some code from this link
http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=51850
but it does not work and even throw any error

```
if ($product_info['quantity'] < $quantity) {
   $json['error']['warning'] = sprintf($this->language->get('error_understock'), $product_info['quantity']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this code help you

```
<script>
$('#input-quantity').on('keyup',function(event){
    var a = $(this).val();
    var total = a.length;
    var pat = '/^[a-zA-Z]+$/';
    if(total == 1 && a == 0)
    {
        $(this).val('');
    } else if(a.match(/^[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z][0-9]|[0-9][a-zA-Z]+$/) ) {
        $(this).val('');
    }
});
</script>
```

Put this code in catalog/view/theme/default/template/product.tpl

Comment: it works but when if i leave empty the input box, it get accepted, and say successfully added, but in cart no product is there. so validation should be for empty field also, sorry i forgot to mention this in my question

Answer (score 1):

Don't need any other validation for this, in the front-end,minimum quantity validation can be controlled from the admin panel for every product separately.Check the product form you can find the option.

Comment: after adding minimum Quantity from admin also it does not work, that why i have given demo link itself